# Laravel 4 eloquent query returns an old database value instead of the updated one

Tags: php, laravel-4, mysqli, eloquent

I have a `Book` table that has a column for stocks count. For example the beginning stocks of a certain book is `100`.

```
BOOKS
book_id | book_stocks | book_isbn
1       | 100         | 123123123
```

when i run this code it will output '100'.

```
$book = Book::where('book_isbn','=',$credentials['book_isbn'])->get();
        foreach ($book as $b) {
            echo $b->book_stocks;
        }
```

Then a part of my code will `decrement` this stock once a user reserves a book. Here's the code.

```
Book::where('book_isbn','=',$credentials['book_isbn'])->decrement('book_stocks');
```

When i check my database it now becomes

```
BOOKS
book_id | book_stocks | book_isbn
1       | 99          | 123123123
```

But when i run this code again.

```
$book = Book::where('book_isbn','=',$credentials['book_isbn'])->get();
        foreach ($book as $b) {
            echo $b->book_stocks;
        }
```

The output is still '100'.

I don't know where it saves that old stock value.

I'm sure with my database connection, i tried to clear cache etc.

Does anyone know the reason behind this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: When you cleared cache, what did you run? And is `book_id` supposed to be `book_isbn`, or is there another table that you haven't shown us?

Comment: @nuc , i run the Book::where('book_isbn','=',$credentials['book_isbn'])->get().. The book_isbn is part of the books table.. sorry I forget to include it

Comment: And what command/things are you running to clear cache? Are you running `php artisan cache:clear`? As I want to rule out cached fragments. I don't think the issue is eloquent caching as you haven't said you're calling `remember()`. I'd also do a force refresh in your browser (shift + ctrl + R or cmd + shift + R).

Comment: @nuc i only cleared the one stored in the browser. i tried to run that  php artisan cache:clear and do a force refresh. Still the data fetched is not updated. I also notice that when the value in the database is 99 it shows 100, when 298 it shows 300.

Comment: omg, the problem is the data type, it was set as float -_-, i change it now to double and it works ... thanks @nuc for the help :D

Comment: Thats odd as you're not storing any precision. I'd change your column to an integer, as there's no use for decimals in stock (can't have .18 of a book). But, glad you solved your problem.